# How to upgrade a chaincode correctly?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

**Problem:**

I created a fabric network with six organizations after that I install a chaincode. Later I change some code parts then I try to update it with this command.

```
peer chaincode upgrade -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C myc -n mycc l node -v 2.1 -c '{"Args":["init"]}' -P "AND ('Org2MSP.peer','Org1MSP.peer','Org3MSP.peer','Org4MSP.peer','Org5MSP.peer','Org6MSP.peer')"
```

It leaves me this error on the terminal.

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not
>   successful, error code 500, msg cannot get package for chaincode
>   (trafficfine:2.1)

This is the logs of that particular peer.

> 2019-05-09 03:47:15.564 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 199
>   [myc][b0a46f15] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc" 2019-05-09
>   03:47:15.565 UTC [lscc] executeDeployOrUpgrade -> ERRO 19a cannot get
>   package for chaincode (mycc:2.1)-err:open
>   /var/hyperledger/production/chaincodes/mycc.2.1: no such file
>   or directory 2019-05-09 03:47:15.565 UTC [endorser] callChaincode ->
>   INFO 19b [myc][b0a46f15] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (1ms)
>   2019-05-09 03:47:15.566 UTC [endorser] ProcessProposal -> ERRO 19c
>   [myc][b0a46f15] simulateProposal() resulted in chaincode
>   name:"lscc"  response status 500 for txid:
>   b0a46f156bdea0cdb2a99b15a2d5519d26cb9b5832ec4b311339a38263661b9f

I tried to lot to figure out a solution to this problem. Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: i think you are missing a "-" in -l node flag

Comment: You need to install the updated chaincode package first before you can issue the upgrade command.